# How to check if a variable was incremented in JS?

Tags: javascript, increment

How do I check if a value has been incremented in JS?

```
var count = 0; 

function A () {
    /// creates random nodes
    /// does some math, outputs e1, e2, e3, etc
    count ++; 
    }

function toggle(count) {
    if (count ++ occurred) && (toggle.checked) {
    /// then take e1, e2, e3 and store in array X ...
    /// take array X and count, put into CSV file, send to designated email 
       }
    }
```

I have function A working fine, but the tricky part is how to record the e1, e2, e3 into array X only when the toggle is on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you know the start value, you can check if the current value is greater than the initial value.

Comment: what for is *toggle*?

Comment: There is no generic "this has been changed" functionality. You have to keep a reference to the initial value of the variable, check the variable again later and see if it's different. Although even that doesn't guarantee no change has happened as you might have had `val++` followed by `val--`.

Comment: If you want to be sure that something changed, you can add a flag (another variable), and set it to `true` whenever you change the `count` variable.

Comment: Have you considered using a setter? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Comment: to store `e1`, `e2`, and `e3` in array `X`, you can use `X = [e1, e2, e3]`

Comment: What kind of function signature is `function A`? There's no `()`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `boolean` variable to check if `count` has been incremented. After checking it's status once, it's state should be reseted to prepare it for the next check.

```
var count = 0; 
let incremented = false;

function a {
  /// does some stuff
  count ++; 
  incremented = true;
}

function b(count) {
  if ( incremented && toggle.checked ) {
    /// then do xyz...
    incremented = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Even though this seems like a classic [XyProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), there are some cases where you might want to react to the change of a value. In which case this would be a way of achiving that:

```js
const observer = (filter, onChange, obj) => new Proxy(obj, {
  set(target, key, value) {
    if (filter(key, target[key], value)) {
      onChange(key, target[key], value);
    }
    target[key] = value;
    return true;
  }
});

const triggerOnIncrement = (key, oldValue, newValue) => oldValue < newValue;
const onValueChanged = (key, oldValue, newValue) => {
  console.log(`${key} was changed from ${oldValue} to ${newValue}`);
};
const _ = observer(triggerOnIncrement, onValueChanged, {
  count: 0,
});

_.count++;
_.count++;
_.count++;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to check that at least once the variable *count* is incremented, you can use directly *count* as condition:

```
function b(count) {
    if (count) && (toggle.checked) {
    /// then do xyz...
       }
}
```

In JS if a variable x is 0, will be considered as "false" in a IF statement.